# how to preload a child state within ui-view in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I have the following states

```
.state('candidate', {
        url: '/candidate',
        templateUrl: 'partials/candidate.html',
        controller: 'CandidateCtrl'
    })
    .state('candidate.newcandidate', {
        url: '/newcandidate',
        templateUrl: 'partials/candidate/candidate-candidate.html'
    })
    .state('candidate.followupcandidate', {
        url: '/followupcandidate',
        templateUrl: 'partials/candidate/candidate-followupcandidate.html'
    })
```

This is my view

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item"><a ui-sref=".newcandidate">New candidate</a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><a ui-sref=".followupcandidate">Follow Up candidate</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div id="candidate-views" ui-view></div>
        </div>
```

When candidate view is loaded, nothing get loaded in

```
<div id="candidate-views" ui-view></div>.
```

I want

```
candidate.newcandidate
```

child state to load without clicking on

```
<li class="list-group-item"><a ui-sref=".newcandidate">New candidate</a></li>
```

I tried

```
$urlRouterProvider
.when('/candidate', '/candidate/newcandidate')
```

but this doesn't do anything.